# UI design examples?

Tags: graphics, gui, interface, ui-design

I am not asking the theory of UI design, or how to do one, I am asking for examples and resources, like... How to draw this fiddly stuff, or how to code another circular thing, or a gallery of game menus, etc...

I am seeking myself specifically sci-fi stuff, but no problem putting other stuff, references are never enough!

EDIT: I am neither looking logic code, neither software tutorials... I am looking for stuff like this:

"Oh, there are this cool GUI on castlevania: http://xbox360media.ign.com/xbox360/image/article/759/759732/castlevania-symphony-of-the-night-20070130115858695.jpg Where the gui looks like made of bone, and it is shown on on the screen by drawing a rectangle textured with the blue bar, and then a transparent bony image is drawn over it..."

Got it now?

Comment: If you intend for this question to be a list, please mark it as CW.

Comment: I don't figured yet how to do it, sorry :/

Comment: I took care of it.

Answer (score 2):

[Menu display for a RPG game tutorial](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/interface-tutorials/how-to-make-a-menu-interface-for-a-fantasy-themed-iphone-game/)
[Tuning dial/knob in photoshop guide](http://blog.guifx.com/2009/04/03/creating-a-knob-in-photoshop/)
[Sci-fi type loading wheel thing :P](http://www.adobetutorialz.com/articles/2966/1/Loading-Interface)

Answer (score 0):

[Gimp Tutorials](http://www.gimp-tutorials.com/) will show you how to draw stuff.